# Pandas Dataframe Groupby Apply Lambda Function With Multiple Column Returns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, apply

I couldn't find anything on SO on this. What I'm trying to do is generate 4 new columns on my existing dataframe, by applying a separate function with 4 specific columns as inputs and return 4 output columns that are not the 4 initial columns. However, the function requires me to slice the dataframe by conditions before usage. I have been using for loops and appending, but it is extremely slow. I was hoping that there was a way to do a MapReduce-esque operation, where it would take my DataFrame, do a groupby and apply a function I separately wrote.

The function has multiple outputs, so just imagine a function like this:

```
    def func(a,b,c,d):
        return f(a),g(b),h(c),i(d)
```

where f,g,h,i are different functions performed on the inputs. I am trying to do something like:

```
    import pandas as pd

    df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(10),
                       'b': range(10),
                       'c': range(10),
                       'd':range(10},
                       'e': [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1])

    df.groupby('e').apply(lambda df['x1'],df['x2'],df['x3'],df['x4'] =
                          func(df['a'],df['b'],df['c'],df['d']))
```

Wondering if this is possible. If there are other functions out there in the library/ more efficient ways to go about this, please do advise. Thanks.

EDIT: Here's a sample output

```
   a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i 
   --------------------------
   0  0  0  0  0  f1 g1 h1 i1
   1  1  1  1  1  f2 g2 h2 i2
    ... and so on
```

The reason why I'd like this orientation of operations is due to the function's operations being reliant on structures within the data (hence the groupby) before performing the function. Previously, I obtained the unique values and iterated over them while slicing the dataframe up, before appending it to a new dataframe. Runs in quadratic time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
def f(data):
    data['a2']=data['a']*2 #or whatever function/calculation you want
    data['b2']=data['b']*3 #etc etc
    #e.g. data['g']=g(data['b'])
    return data

df.groupby('e').apply(f)
```

Comment: This works! My final solution nested the function within the new function, but works all the same. Thanks for this

Comment: Btw, another good alternative might be to use the `groupby.transform` function. In that case, you'd call it on one column at a time and then append the columns to your dataframe. It may be significantly more efficient.